# Python- Iterating through columns in csv file

Tags: python, django, email, csv

I am working on a project where I will have to iterate through a csv file.
I want to see if the 4 column(3rd slot) of each row will have an email address already in my dictionary that has the person's name and email address. If they are I want to send them back an attachment. I'm not very familiar with Python, so I want to see if I'm heading in the right direction

Here is a sample code:

import csv

```
with open("file.csv") as csv_file:
for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
    if row[3] in data_dict:
        email = EmailMessage('subject', 'body', [address@something.com])
        email.attach_file('/folder/name.csv')
        email.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

When involved with attachments I'd advise the [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) package (full disclose: I'm the developer)

Obtain it by running:

```
pip install yagmail # for python 2
pip3 install yagmail # for python3
```

Then:

```
import yagmail

yag = yagmail.SMTP('myemail', 'mypassword')

with open("file.csv") as csv_file:
for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
    row = row.split(',')
    if row[3] in data_dict:
        contents = ['See my file attached', '/folder/name.csv']
        yag.send(row[3] + '@email.com', 'subject', contents)
```

Note that anything that can be opened as a file will be attached (when passed to the `contents` argument), so if `/folder/name.csv` is a valid path in that list, it will be sent as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        cols = line.split(',')
        if cols[3] in data_dict:
            email = EmailMessage('subject', 'body', [address@something.com])
            email.attach_file('/folder/name.csv')
            email.send()
```